# trouble installing pyserial

Tags: python, installation, pyserial

I have not managed to install pyserial for use with Spyder 3.9 (launched from Anaconda.Navigator) in Windows 10.

I tried <conda install -c conda-forge pyserial> from the Windows command terminal and some files were installed, but import pyserial from the Spyder console gives the response <ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyserial'>.

Then I tried to install it again from the Spyder console with pip install pyserial, which gave the response <Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in c:\users\father\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.4)>
Then I tried pip uninstall pyserial, which locked up the Spyder console altogether.

I'm afraid it looks a bit of a mess.  Can anybody suggest how to clear it up and make pyserial available?

Comment: Maybe your problem is due to the fact that you should write `import serial` instead of `import pyserial`...

Comment: Thanks Laurent.  That seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should juste write `import serial` instead of `import pyserial`.